# python3.5 requests.get() error in .py file but not in interactive shell

Tags: python

Funny thing is happening... I have this code (.py)

```
import requests

res = requests.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com/files/rj.txt')
print(len(res))
print(res.text[:250])
```

which, when I run it, produces "AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'" error. But when I type the same thing in the interactive shell, I get no errors. 
Any idea why this is happening? (I'm using python 3.5)
Thanks

Comment: Are you running the .py code module and the python shell from the same directory?  I'm guessing not, and I'm also guessing that the directory from which you run the .py module contains another module named `requests.py`, which is being imported instead of the "real" requests module.

Comment: Thank you. Directories are the same but my .py file was named requests.py (same as module name). After I renamed the file, it worked. Thanks again. I won't make that mistake again.